# How can we bind certain pixels of tkinter window or frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there anyway to bind certain coordinates of `window` or `frame` like when mouse enter these coordinates `call` this `function` etc. The reason is that i want to bind these coordinates for `scrollbar`, So I can hide `scrollbar` if user leaves that `position`.

Comment: I really don't get why you would bind to a pixel instead of a widget but you can always bind to `"<Motion>"` and then use `event.x` and `event.y` to check if the mouse is over that pixel/those pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind` and `<Enter>`

Example:

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk

root = Tk()

def hover(event):
    b.config(bg="blue")

def leave(event):
    b.config(bg="white")

b = Button(root, text="Click me!")
b.pack(pady=20)
b.bind("<Enter>", hover)
b.bind("<Leave>", leave)

root.mainloop()
```

For more bindings, you can refer this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-binding-function-in-tkinter/

Comment: i know this. i already mentioned i want to bind pixels.

Comment: @kanwarprogrammer: why do you want to "bind pixels"? In the question you state that your goal is to hide a scrollbar when the mouse leaves. That's exactly what binding to `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` are for.

Comment: @kanwarprogrammer what do you want then?? In the question, you said you want the scrollbar to hide when the cursor isn't there. You can create a function that ```pack_forget```s or ```destroy```s the scrollbar. Bind the function to ```<Leave>``` event.   Then create another function which packs the scrollbar and bind it to ```<Enter>``` event, to a frame. So when the user hovers the cursor over the frame, the scrollbar appears and when he removes the cursor, it disappears.

Comment: Okay i'll bind the frame instead of scrollbar's frame to bind the scrollbar events. @Bryan Okaley.

Comment: Okay i'll bind @Ishaan Jog.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot bind to specific pixels. However, you can simulate that by binding to all mouse movement (eg: `<Motion>`). In the bound function, you can then determine if the mouse is over whatever region you want to have active.

Comment: I litreally post my questions to get answers from you. You're the best,